# Filtering Google Analytics Segments via API

Tags: javascript, google-analytics-api

As some of you may be aware, over recent months there has been a sharp rise in the number of spam referral bots inflating analytics statistics (for example, increased hit count, bounce rate, time on page etc from spam bots like semalt and buttons-for-website). These bots typically cause GA to register a site hit without actually accessing the website. As such, it's not possible to block these referrals via .htaccess or another server-level blocking method.

The work around to this is to create a segment in analytics that filters out these spam bots to leave you with clean site data. I have done this and have a unique ID key for my segment. I also have a working Google script (JavaScript) that takes data from analytics and dumps it into Google Sheets. However, the script is only able (at present) to pull analytics data with these spam referrals included.

My question is whether it's technically possible to pull data using the API and then apply a segment to filter out all the crap data. If so, does anyone have any prior experience with how to do this with JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

You filter one of the view of your property. You should use :
https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/ there you could use the "view select".

This tool combined with the Google documentation will allow you to build an extractor if needed.